# Is it possible to show a collapse saved in a different file, in the page requested?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Let's say I have a nav bar in my index with 4 button tag, right now they show the content in a different page, for example: button 1 sends me to page/button1page.php

What I want to do is, integrate those 4 pages in a single one, using collapse, I just don't know how, right now all I get is to show 4 different collapse but the code for every collapse is in the same file (my index), and I want it separately, for example, when I press button 1, I want to be able to display the content in a collapse inside the same page (index) instead of going to index/button1page.php

This is my test code, it works with all the code in the same file.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="1" onclick="action(this.value)"
    href="collapse1.html#collapse1">
    Collapse 1 con button
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="2" onclick="action(this.value)">
    Collapse 2 con button
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" value="3" onclick="action(this.value)">
    Collapse 3 con button
</button>



<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse3">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Parrafo del collapse 3
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function action(valor) {
        if (valor == 1) {
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (valor == 2) {
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (valor == 3) {
            document.getElementById("collapse3").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("collapse1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("collapse2").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You say it all works in one file so it really isn't clear what the specific problem is

Comment: I wan't to have only my buttons in the index.php and a different file for every collapse (collapse1.php, collapse2.php) but show all those collapse in the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is not clearly stated, but from what I've understood, could this be what you want? [example link](https://replit.com/@gzappy/AlienatedTalkativeMath)

Comment: All you have to do is include the php file to display in the collapsible part

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very, very much, you saved me a lot of work